# convert numbers to 26base with only letters

Tags: php

I need to **convert** number in "Alphabetic" Counting System, similar to excel spreadsheets:

> convert(1) == "A";
>   convert(2) == "B";
>   ...
>   convert(26) == "Z";
>   convert(27) == "AA";
>   ...
>   convert(52) == "AZ";
>   convert(53) == "BA";
>   ...
>   convert(702 ) == "ZZ";
>   convert(703 ) == "AAA";

this is my code:

```
function convert($n){
    if ($n> 26) {
        $tmp = floor($n / 26);
        $n= $n % 26;
        $result = chr(($tmp - 1) + 65) . chr(($n - 1) + 65);
    } else {
        $result = chr(($n- 1) + 65);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

but the output is a bit off:

> @, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z,
>   AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AO, AP, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AV, AW, AX, AY,
>   B@, BA

I tried to tweak the numbers but I can not make it right, any suggestion for a better algorithm ?

Comment: There is no question here...

Comment: And what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: `for($i=1,$out='A';$i<$n;$i++,$out++);return $out;` done.

Comment: Wait, this isn't Code Golf :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol great solution, if you care to add an answer I will be glad to accept it. Small optimization on your code (removing the $i) : `for($out='A';$n-->0;$out++);return $out;`

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of PHP's ability to increment strings as well as numbers:

```
function convert($number) {
    $result = 'A';
    for($i = 1; $i < $number; ++$i) {
        ++$result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qbgXC)

Comment: Specifically, PHP's ability to increment `'Z'` to `'AA'` - other programming languages would increment `'Z'` to `'['` due to incrementing the character code.

Comment: It is nice PHP can increase from 'Z' to 'AA'. Still, convert(1,000,000) would be very slow.

Comment: Not as fast as a decent encoder using bases, but not too shabby; and a useful trick to be aware of.... I just wish PHP allowed you to decrement in the same way :(

Answer (score 2):

Based on @NiettheDarkAbsol comment, 
this is a quick solution if the expected calls are for small numbers:

```
function convert($n) {
    for($out = 'A'; --$n > 0; $out++);
    return $out;
}
```

From [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  something  like this

```
function convert($n)
{
    if ($n <= 0) return "";

    $r = "";
    $c  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    do {
        $n -= 1;
        $r = $c[$n % 26] . $r;
        $n = intval($n / 26);
    } while($n > 0);

    return strtoupper($r);
}

var_dump(convert(703));  // AAA
var_dump(convert(52));   // AZ
```

The key is `$n -= 1` in every loop because the number system you are using have  no concept of zero (0).

Comment: Side-note, you can use `$c = range('A','Z');` to get your character list, and using uppercase in the first place removes the need for `strtoupper` at the end.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, nice tip ^^

Comment: This doesn't handle numbers correctly, for example fails on "0", "1" should be "B"

Answer (score 0):

This is a corrected version:

```
function DecToBase26($n)
{
    if ($n < 0) return "";

    $r = "";
    $Digits = range("A", "Z");
    do 
    {
        $r = $Digits[$n % 26] . $r;
        $n = intval($n / 26);
    } while($n > 0);

    return $r;
}


var_dump(DecToBase26(0)); 
var_dump(DecToBase26(1));  
var_dump(DecToBase26(25));  
var_dump(DecToBase26(26));
var_dump(DecToBase26(27));
```